# How to inherit and change a components styles with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have `OverviewItem` which takes 2 props and is a `styled-component` I would like to adjust just one style on this component, this is possible via: [styling any component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component). Is the only way to share styles by creating a wrapper component?

```
const OverviewItemStyled = styled.div`
  margin-right: 10px;
`

export const OverviewItem = ({ title, value }: OverviewItemProps) => {
  return (
    <OverviewItemStyled>{title}, {value}<OverviewItemStyled>
  )
}

const OverviewSubTitle = styled(OverviewItem)`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`

<OverviewSubTitle /> //no margin-bottom
```

Comment: did the below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `className` prop to the base component you want to overwrite:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const BaseBox = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
`;

const Component1 = ({name, className}) => <BaseBox className={className}>{name}</BaseBox>;

const Component2 = styled(Component1)`
  background: green;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Component1 name="widget 1" />
      <Component2 name="widget 2" />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-default-forked-xp250?file=/src/App.js)

[Ref](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)